# How to fill areas with different colors in Fusion Tables layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to display areas belongs to zip codes using FusionTables , But I need to use different colors to each zip code are depends on some logic I have. How can I individually get reference to each Fusion Layer item area so that I can handle them individually . Or is there any other solution ?

```
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(1499916);
    layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry' FROM 1499916");
    layer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: @person down voted.. any comment on why ?

Answer (score 1):

Google has an article about creating different styles for each item in a fusion table. Check it out here:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/mouseover_map_styles